# Перестал работать AJAX в Contact Form 7 после интеграции с reCaptcha

Tags: ajax, wordpress, contact-form7

Перестал работать AJAX в Contact Form 7 после интеграции с reCaptcha. До этого все работало как надо. Страница теперь перезагружается. Отключил интеграцию, и также не работает AJAX. Движок Wordpress
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Ну я не знаю, что еще написать можно. Работало все нормально. Подключил рекаптчу - перестало работать. Отключил (откатил) все как было. И все равно не работает. Сталкивался же может быть кто-то. Их и спрашиваю

Comment: Консоль посмотрите, может где-то ошибка, проверьте что включен REST api, а вообще причин может быть много.

Comment: проверьте что включен REST api , а как проверить? У меня домен включен в список доменов в гугл Рекаптча. А в консоли ошибок нет

Comment: Загадками говорите. Способов интеграции с reCaptcha миллион, включая ручные. Вот этот плагин https://wordpress.org/plugins/invisible-recaptcha/ точно работает с CF7, только вчера ставил на один сайт.

Comment: У самого плагина Contact Form 7 есть инфтерфейс интеграции в админке WorPress